# How to convert image to bytearray?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I want create a video steaming on socket, but I can't convert an image to bytearray.
why i can't convert image form camera to  bytearray?

```py
CHUNK=1024 lnF = 640*480*3    
wvs = WebcamVideoStream(0).start()    
while True: for x in range(1):
        try:
            frame = wvs.read()
            cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # cv2.imshow('frame',cv2_im)
            # if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            #     break
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
            # print("frame :", frame)
            frame = np.array(frame, dtype = np.uint8).reshape(1, lnF)
            # print("frame :",frame)
            jpg = bytearray(frame)
            # print("jpg_as_text", jpg_as_text)
            # print("ACCEP")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is? Also, don't do things like `except Exception as e: print(e)`, it's bad practice.

Comment: Why do you name your `bytearray` as `jpeg_as_text` when it is neither a JPEG nor text? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If an answer has helped you, please accept one. If not, please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

An cv2 image is stored as an [numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). To get the byte representation of an numpy.ndarray you can just use the [numpy.ndarray.tobytes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) method to convert you image. In your code it would look something like this:

```py
jpg = frame.tobytes()
```

The length of the bytes when using the .tobytes method is actually a bit less when using is actually a bit smaller than the pickle.dumps method and a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import pickle

 frame = wvs.read()
 cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
 frame = np.array(frame, dtype = np.uint8).reshape(1, lnF)

 # packing:

 pickled = pickle.dumps(frame)
 byte_array_pickle = str.encode(pickled)
```

and

```
#unpacking

unicode_pickle = incoming_data.decode()
original_image = pickle.loads(unicode_pickle)
```